# Adding an object to skygear Social Login API

Tags: reactjs, redux, skygear

I am using skygear social login. i want to append an object along with the request to the socialLogin api.The values in the object are a field in my UI application which needs to be saved in my db. The googleoauth 2.0 uses state to pass additional data in the query params . However I am not able to do so with skygear.

this is my code

```
function oauthlogin(provider,Cname,Cage){
    return (
          skygear.auth.loginOAuthProviderWithPopup('google',options: 
          {Cname,cage}).then(res=>{console.log(res})
    )
}
```

I have tried options and state as it was given in the official documentation of Skygear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [skygear.auth.loginOAuthProviderWithPopup](https://docs.skygear.io/js/reference/latest/class/packages/skygear-core/lib/auth.js~AuthContainer.html#instance-method-loginOAuthProviderWithPopup) does accept options, but they are for auth only, which will not be saved as a field in the user profile.

Suggested way: save the fields via [save record API](https://docs.skygear.io/guides/cloud-db/crud/js/#updating-records) after the login is successful (in the `then` part).

```
function oauthlogin(provider,Cname,Cage){
    return (
      skygear.auth.loginOAuthProviderWithPopup('google')
        .then((user) => {
          // save the user data here instead
          user.Cname = Cname;
          user.Cage = Cage;
          skygear.publicDB.save(user).then(res => console.log(res));
        })
    )
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Does it get Worked?